# travel outside of/out of SOMETHING

Tags: meaning

> Many people like to travel out of their country.
>
> Many people like to travel outside of their country.

I think there must be a difference but what is it?

Answer (score 3):

The former—with *out of*—would mean *leaving*, *departing*. It focuses on the changing of status from within the country to without.

The latter—with *outside*—focuses on the various destinations’ being foreign, rather than domestic. It is also more idiomatic.

Comment: Yes. London to Paris is travelling out of the UK. Brussels to Paris is travelling outside of the UK.

Comment: I don't understand. Say I am in Germany and I say "I plant to travel out of Germany", how does it differ from saying "I plan to travel outside of Germany." In both cases I leave Germany.

Comment: @user1425 It's like the difference between "*I plan to walk **out of** the house*" and "*I plan to walk **outside** the house*". "walk out of" means "exit", and "walk outside" means walk while outside. Sure, you have to exit the house in order to walk outside, but "exit" and "walk outside" don't have the same meaning.